# error reading a column value

Tags: vb6

The application it was working fine with database IBM Informix...now we are migrating to SQL SERVER 2012.. and this starts to happen.

Follow an example.

```
sql = "select r_e_c_n_o_, zb1_larg, zb1_verniz from " & arq("zb1")
sql = sql & " where zb1_filial='" & filial("zb1") & "' and zb1_cod='" & dados_rotulo.b1_cod
sql = sql & "' and zb1_revpro='" & dados_rotulo.zb1_revpro & "'"
sql = sql & " and (d_e_l_e_t_ is null or d_e_l_e_t_ = ' ')"
rst_zb1.Open sql, cnn_db, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly
```

If I read like below it works fine.

```
recno = rst_zb1.Fields!r_e_c_n_o_ ' return ok, return value: 5000
larg = rst_zb1.Fields!zb1_larg
verniz = rst_zb1.Fields!zb1_verniz
```

If I change the sequence it doesn´t return any value for recno column cause before it has read the last column of the query. Why this is happening?

```
larg = rst_zb1.Fields!zb1_larg
verniz = rst_zb1.Fields!zb1_verniz
recno = rst_zb1.Fields!r_e_c_n_o_ 'return 0, it should return value: 5000
```

Comment: Which database engine are you using? DAO,RDO,ADO?

Comment: ADO....I´ve updated my question with more details about whats happening, please checkout.

Answer (score 0):

try opening a recrodset with `adOpenKeyset` or `adOpenDynamic` instead of `adOpenForwardOnly`. See if that helps.